# Error with simple spring MVC using IntelliJ with Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-mvc

Using IntelliJ 9, Tomcat 6, maven project (pom.xml based).

Running the application returns the error, not sure if it is a tomcat deployment issue or not.

Strange thing, when I hit the refresh button on the browser, I don't see any errors in IntelliJ's server output window.

I have tomcat setup with intelliJ to use the war-exploded artifact.

Does Tomcat just use the directory under my projects?

Does it modify tomcat's server xml to do this?  Or is this does on the fly somehow?

I want to know what files get run with tomcat runs, for some reason I'm getting a 404 at:

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

I just setup a simple Spring MVC application, I have a HomeController:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String Index() {
        return "hello, world";
    }
}
```

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mymvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

     <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/src/main/web/WEB-INF/spring/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mymvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

servlet-context.xml

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.debugging" />

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
```

**Update**

My exploded war looks like:

```
/mymvc_war_exploded
/mymvc_war_exploded/web-inf (it has classes folder and inside is my homecontroller.class)
/mymvc_war_exploded/lib
```

I don't see my views folder, or my .xml files anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

You should be returning the path of a view (as in the tutorial), not just a string, assuming you're going through it step-by-step. Since you haven't shown a resolver definition, I'm assuming you're not returning view names yet.

Check the logs, too.

Also, by convention, Java method names begin with a lower-case letter.

Comment: Do you mean that just returning a string will cause to not work?  I just wanted it to return something, yes ignoring view files for now.

Comment: do I have to create any goals for this to work? I'm confused how tomcat hooks into my application i.e. where does it store my .war file and explode it?

Comment: @Blankman No, returning just a string won't work--see [the tutorial we were discussing earlier](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/01/04/green-beans-getting-started-with-spring-mvc/). No, you don't need to create any goals as long as you're still running inside IntelliJ--the IDE handles artifact deployment.

Comment: ok it seems for some reason my exploded war isn't correct, see my updated question above to see what it looks like (updating it now).

Comment: ok it worked with me just having it like I had it before w/o the view, just returning a string.  the issue was my module content root was not pointing to the right directory.